# How to submit multiple types of disabled input(input, select, textarea tag helpers) from one form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand you can't submit disabled inputs at all. I've just setup a form disabling all inputs(input, select etc.) for the user to view only. How do I successfully post values from the form for the multiple types

I've used jquery to disable all inputs (includes input, select etc.) so that the form appears to be "readonly" to a user. I can only seem to get one of the input/select/textarea types to pass using onsubmit, but I can't figure out how to get all the input types to be passed/enabled onsubmit.

This is how I disabled all the inputs, the name of the from is #form:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form :input").prop("readonly", true);
    });
</script>
```

This only enables the inputs with the tag helper input:

```
onsubmit="$(this).find('input').prop('disabled', false)"
```

At the moment the data passed from the form is only input ones, but I need select (selected dropwdowns which have been passed in) and textarea ones to be passed from the form.

Comment: Change `find('input')` to `find(':input')` as you originally have it. Also, don't use inline event handlers. Change `onsubmit` to an unobtrusive event handler. Also note that in your first example you set `readonly`, which would be the correct way to do this, in the second you use `disabled` - there seems to be a mismatch there.

Comment: If the entire form is 'readonly' then what data do you expect to save back to the database?

Comment: Apologies I was testing the readonly just before this, and had not changed it back to disbaled, the (':input') works perfectly thanks for the help @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following example.

```js
$( "#form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault(); // do not submit
  $( "#form" ).find('input, select').prop('disabled',false);
  $( "#form" )[0].submit();  
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="/1">
  <input type="text" readonly disabled="disabled" value="value1" name="field1">
  <input type="text" readonly disabled="disabled" value="value2" name="field2">  
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```